# queryset update using F() object don't works in datamigrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm trying to create a datamigration using update queryset method. I have a complex migration process for my case, so i faced the following problem. The simple example

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


def move_data(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model("my_app", 'MyModel')
    MyModel.objects.all().update(new_field=models.F('old_field'))

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('orders', '0057_auto_20170410_1513'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(move_data),
    ]
```

In my case i got FieldError. F() object can't resolve the field `old_field`, but if i will use something like this

```
for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
    obj.new_field=obj.old_field
    obj.save()
```

instead of

```
MyModel.objects.all().update(new_field=models.F('old_field'))
```

all will be good

I have a few models inherited from one base model and i need to move some fields from on of the child model to parent. So i made this with the following steps

1. rename the old fields in child
2. create the new fields in parent
3. move data from old fields to new fields
4. delete the old fields

I faced this at the 3 step and can't understand why it don't works

Can somebody provide some explanation of this?

Is it related to the model state rendering process somehow?

**UPD.**
The simplified definition of models

```
class Base(models.Model):
    pass

class MyModel1(Base):
    pass

class MyModel2(Base):
    field = models.IntegerField()
```

Step 1 and 2 - Rename field and create in base class

```
class Base(models.Model):
    field = models.IntegerField()

class MyModel1(Base):
    pass

class MyModel2(Base):
    old_field = models.IntegerField()
```

Step 3 - moving data

Will work -

```
for obj in MyModel2.objects.all():
    obj.field=obj.old_field # the same as obj.base_ptr = obj.old_field; obj.base_ptr.save()
    obj.save()
```

Won't work -

```
MyModel2.objects.all().update(field=models.F('old_field'))
```

Comment: It should works in the `F('old_field')` way. Can you please include the Model definition of `MyModel`?

Comment: mmm, old_value is a value from another Model? Check this from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once): "However, unlike F() objects in filter and exclude clauses, you can’t introduce joins when you use F() objects in an update – you can only reference fields local to the model being updated. If you attempt to introduce a join with an F() object, a FieldError will be raised"

Comment: I've added the model definitions. And no, i'm not using the fields from other models. I just now realised what can be wrong

When i move a field from inherited model to base model, it was moved from one table in database to other, so the data also should be moved between tables. i'm working only with one model in code, but on database level it will be two different tables. So in this case F() won't work. Please correct me if i'm not right

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think you can't use F in this case. Maybe you could perform a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) or iterate with for loop. In the second case, use an [iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) and you will save a lot of memory in the process.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, how did you solve it? Just did the for loop?

Comment: Yes, just with the loop. F object won't work if fields are in different tables even if the model is the same. In my case this happened because i tried to move data from child model to base model and if base model is not abstract, then base and child model will have it's own table in db. If you don't want make a for loop, you can perform migration with pure sql code, it will be much faster